# Daisy chaining PoE switches for IP camera system

Tags: switch, camera, ip-camera, power-over-ethernet

I have to design a surveillance system for a small factory that covers approximately 300 meters in length, every 40 meters I should place two cameras, until the end of the factory.

My question: is it better to place PoE switches every 40 meters with an external power supply or use PoE Extenders every 100 meters and then between one intersection and another place PoE switches without external power?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use PoE power injectors to power the cameras if there is mains power nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Uh ?

Normally you can't power a PoE switch by PoE and have that same switch supply PoE power to other devices.
Most PoE switches don't even support that config.
(In theory you could power a PoE (ad standard) switch A with a PoE+ powerfeed from another switch B (at standard) and have enough surplus power left that switch A could then power 2 additional devices with standard PoE. But that would be an extreme niche application and I don't know of any switches that support that.)

In general each PoE switch (ad, af or at PoE standard) needs a real power-supply.
Old PoE switch technology (passive PoE) could be made to work as you envision, but that sort of equipment is not compatible with equipment following the ad, af and at standards, which is the current tech.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do away with trying to chain PoE devices or somehow daisy chaining Ethernet.

If your factory already has Ethernet switches connecting other machines that you can piggy-back off then I'd simply use a single port PoE injector. Something that takes in Ethernet, needs a standard mains socket and puts out PoE compliant Ethernet connection. Something like one of these: [TP-Link TL-PoE150S](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-LINK-TL-PoE150S-Injector-Adapter-Compliant-Black/dp/B001PS9E5I)

If the factory has *no* existing data cabling then unless I was intending to wire up a lot more devices, and so set up multiple switches to cover the entire factory floor, then given the size of the place I would simply ignore standard Ethernet and go straight to fibre.

Just like PoE Injectors there are also PoE Media Converters that can take in fibre and power and then put out a PoE Ethernet connection. [Star-tech IMC1GSFP60W](https://www.startech.com/en-gb/networking-io/imc1gsfp60w) is a media converter that accepts standard SFP modules, or there is a similar but cheaper [FS PMC-1F1T](https://www.fs.com/uk/products/101490.html) unit. All you have to do is lay the fibre and get relevant SFP modules.

If this is a factory using lots of heavy machinery then fibre will be more resilient to electromagnetic noise from the machinery, can all come back to a single cabinet without complicated cable routing and daisy-chaining to get enough 100m ethernet hops.

Fibre may be more expensive than standard ethernet but it will be faster and potentially more robust in a factory environment.